# Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList' requires 1 type arguments

Tags: android, xamarin

```
public IReadOnlyList POIs 
{

    get 
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
```

**Exception:**
C:\Users\Nouman Aslam\Documents\Projects\POIApp\POIApp\POIJsonService.cs(10,10): Error CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList' requires 1 type arguments (CS0305) (POIApp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IReadOnlyList is a generic.  You need to specify the type it is using, like

```
IReadOnlyList<string> or IReadOnlyList<int> or IReadOnlyList<MyClass>
```