# Error CS0305 - Using the generic type 'GenericResult<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Tags: c#, .net, generics

<sub>Research:
[Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList' requires 1 type arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617923/using-the-generic-type-system-collections-generic-ireadonlylist-requires-1-typ) and [Error CS0305 Using the generic type 'Memory' requires 1 type arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916183/error-cs0305-using-the-generic-type-memory-requires-1-type-arguments), etc</sub>

*I've seen the other answers and I thought this issue would be pretty common problem.*

I'm getting this error:

> Error CS0305  Using the generic type 'GenericResult' requires 1 type arguments

I have a method that returns a generic result:

```
public async Task<GenericResult<bool>> Handle ...
```

It's because I'm trying to instantiate this GenericResult class with a primative and its not working:

```
return new GenericResult(true);
```

This is the constructor of the GenericResult class:

```
    public GenericResult(T info)
    {
        Info= info;
    }
```

How to resolve?

Comment: [Why can't the C# constructor infer type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3570167/15498). Note that with instance methods, type inference may still allow you to omit the type parameter, unlike what your answer states.

Answer (score -1):

<sub>NOTE: Answering my own question to help others in the future</sub>

**Solution:**

When you see a method or Ctor with a signature containing **T**, typically as the first argument in the parameter then you know to call it with generics, eg:

```
return new GenericResult<bool>(true);
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. Generic types can often be inferred, but not for constructors.

Comment: I'm answering my own question